# Apostrophes showing up as ΓÇÖ after converting from Windows to Linux

Tags: encoding

I'm trying to move my WordPress blog from Windows to Linux, but I'm seeing a weird character encoding problem in the Linux version that I'm not seeing on Windows. (I had thought it was an issue with the way I used `mysqldump` to export the data, but after upgrading mysql, dumping, checking, etc., I'm pretty sure I did that part OK). The data in the database on Windows is exactly the same as it is on Linux.

Here's what apostrophe's look like on my Windows blog:

[image]

And here's how it appears on the Linux blog:

[image]

As you can see, there's a weird `ΓÇÖ` series of characters instead of an apostrophe. Is there a setting in WordPress that I need to change to get it to render it correctly?

More details:

Windows, I'm getting back in the response the following bytes for the single apostrophe:

```
E2 80 99
```

Linux, I'm getting back bytes for `ΓÇÖ`:

```
CE 93 C3 87 C3 96
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being (I think) Powershell's wrangling of the output from mysqldump. In powershell, I had been using:

```
mysqldump -u**** -p**** -h**** wordpress --default-character-set=utf8 | 
   out-file out.sql -Encoding UTF8
```

I was even good about explicitly outputting UTF8 for both `mysqldump` and `out-file`! However, it *seems* (and this is really hard to prove because it's hard to tell what powershell does with UTF8 multi-byte unicode characters once you pass it to `out-file`) that `out-file` is having trouble handling multi-byte unicode characters in UTF8.

I switched to using the plain old Windows command prompt, which outputted data correctly:

```
mysqldump -u**** -p**** -h**** wordpress --default-character-set=utf8 > 
    out.sql
```

Comment: After digging in a little more, I *think* that it might still be `mysqldump`, not powershell, but the weird thing is that for some reason `cmd`'s output works, whereas powershell's does not.

Comment: Yes but instead of correcting just the dump, how do you import the incorrectly encoded file still if that's all you have?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're not using an actual apostrophe, but one of the curly apostrophes, such as those that Microsoft Word might be configured to auto-correct to. There is a chance that your mysqldump was actually exporting it incorrectly. In my test database, both PowerShell and Command Prompt were dumping as `ΓÇÖ`, whereas Cygwin was dumping as `’`. If your export does look fine in those areas, you may want to check the Content-Type return header to see that it is specifying UTF-8. If both of those check out, it could be that the database's encoding needs to be modified.

As an alternative, you could replace any occurrence of `’` with `'`.

Comment: My apologies for the slightly vague answer, but I do not have the ability to comment everywhere yet.

Comment: vague is fine. Those are some good things to check.

Comment: Content type for both is text/html UTF-8. Looking at the source of what was returned, Windows host is returning `’` and Linux host is returning `ΓÇÖ`.

Answer (score 1):

Recently had this same issue in PowerShell and a coworker of mine suggested adding this to the top of my script.

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Once added, `’` stopped outputting as `ΓÇÖ`